Is it UB to write via raw pointer to a variable pointed to by a &mut?
In Rust, &mut aliasing causes undefined behavior. But what happens in the case of pointers and references, as shown below?
fn main() {
    let mut data = 12345;
    let p = &mut data as *mut _;
    let r = &mut data;
    println!("r = {}", r);
    unsafe {
        *p = 54321; // <- Is this UB?
    }
    println!("r = {}", r);
}

Playground
Similar question
Here is a very similar question: Do aliasing mutable raw pointers (*mut T) cause undefined behaviour?
According to the answer to this one, it appears that the use of the += operator causes UB. However, even after reading this, I could not figure out whether *p = causes a UB or not.

Go to your own playground link and select "Miri" from the tools menu. "error: Undefined Behavior: attempting a write access using <2203> at alloc1075[0x0], but that tag does not exist in the borrow stack for this location"

I did not know Miri. Thanks for letting me know!

No problem. Note that Miri does not detect all UB. If Miri says it's UB, then it is. If Miri doesn't say it is, it still could be.

@cdhowie not all UB that miri detects is definitely UB, there are cornercases and it's still not clear if tree- or stacked-borrows are definitive.

In this case, it is definitely UB - r reserves exclusive access to data but *p = ... violates that exclusivity since r was still alive and p was not derived from r.
